# C# Read text file and store values in different lists

Tags: c#, readfile

I have the following problem. I would like to read a text file and store the values in different lists. Therefore I created a class but I have some trouble with the task.

The values in the text file are for example (without the bullet points):

- House 500
- Flat 200
- House 100
- Book 10
- Book 5
- Flat 10

Now I would like to create a list house, list flat etc. and store the values from the text file in this lists.

Could anyone please help me with this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: So lets take a step back, do you know how to make a list? Do you know how to read a file? Do you know how to use string.Split ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Can you show us what you tried so far and what you are stuck on. This is not a coding service. Do you have a defined data structure for example

Comment: HI, You mentioned, you are gettign trouble. are you getting any exceptioln? did you try anything to achieve this task? please share here for more information.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I've tried so far:

```
static void Main()
{
    const string f = "example.txt";

    // 1
    // Declare new List.
    List<string> lines = new List<string>();

    // 2
    // Use using StreamReader for disposing.
    using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader(f))
    {
        // 3
        // Use while != null pattern for loop
        string line;
        while ((line = r.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            // 4
            // Insert logic here.
            // ...
            // "line" is a line in the file. Add it to our List.
            lines.Add(line);
        }
    }

    // 5
    // Print out all the lines.
    foreach (string s in lines)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(s);
    }

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

I was able to read the file and print it to screen. But now I would like to split the list into different lists.

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
static void Main()
{
    const string f = "example.txt";

    // 1
    // Declare new List.
    List<string> house = new List<string>();
    List<string> flat = new List<string>();
    List<string> book = new List<string>();
    // 2
    // Use using StreamReader for disposing.
    using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader(f))
    {
        // 3
        // Use while != null pattern for loop
        string line;
        while ((line = r.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            var arr = line.Split(' ');
            if(arr[0].ToLower()=="house")
            {
                house.Add(arr[1]);
            }
            if(arr[0].ToLower()=="book")
            {
                book.Add(arr[1]);
            }       
            if(arr[0].ToLower()=="flat")
            {
                flat.Add(arr[1]);
            }
        }
    }

    // 5
    // Print out all the lines.
    foreach (string s in lines)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(s);
    }

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```